# How to find duplicates within rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I see lot's of questions and answers about duplicate rows, but mine is different.

I have a table with 15 columns that should be unique with respect to each other, so within a row these 15 fields should all have different values.

How can I check this, or more precisely, I want to select all the rows that do have one or more duplicate values within those 15 fields.

Any pointers?

Comment: Do you have a primary key in the table?

Comment: Seems like a bad database design. Are you able to use a different design? Do you use a scripting or other language?

Comment: "I see lot's of questions and answers about duplicate rows, but mine is different." Yes indeed your question is different because you didn't include table structures, example data and expected results like the others are doing.

Comment: Please add some more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a giant `where` condition:

```
where col1 in (col2, col3, . . . , col15) or
      col2 in (col3, col4, . . ., col15) or
      col14 in (col15)
```

This assumes that none of the values are `NULL`.

You should probably fix the data structure.  The data in the 15 columns should probably be in 15 rows in a junction table.

Comment: The question asks about selecting the rows that have duplicates, not the ones that don't have. You should probably add the negation of the condition as well. I.e. `where col1 in (col2, col3, .. col15) or `

Comment: Ehm, you messed up the negation, you need to use DeMorgans rule.. I'll edit and fix it

Comment: Thanks, this will work. The database is indeed legacy and I will make a new design coming weeks / months.